# Force database tablename for collection relationship in Sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

In a sails project, considering a model `User` and a model `Role`, with a relationship between User and Role :

```
// `User.js
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        ...

        roles: {
            collection: 'role',
            dominant: true
        },

        ...
    }
}
```

For the the database representation, sails/waterline will create following tables :

- table user,
- table role,
- table like `user_roles__role_roles_role` to represent the collection

I know we can force the name for the models USER and ROLE
(with the property 'tablename' : http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes).

But how can we force the name the relationship table ? (Especially this name is quite long and tends to exceed limit).

Comment: I had looked up for same thing, didn't find any way. By the way, which limit are you exceeding?

Comment: @Sangharsh for some collections : Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: ER_TOO_LONG_IDENT: Identifier name 'form_frequencies__formperformancefreq_frequencies_formperformancefreq' is too long

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a two-way relationship, and the Role model has a `users` collection, Sails will expect a table named `role_users__user_roles`, which has the role id first, user id second.

Your example table name would require User to be dominant and would require the Role model to have an attribute named `roles_role` that is a User collection.

To create your own join table, you can use the `through` association method and add a new model that represents the relationship, perhaps `UsersRoles`, and specify the `tableName` in that model definition.

Examples of the `through` association:

- [sails
  docs](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/through-associations)
- [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795389/one-to-many-associations-using-existing-join-table)
- [gist from comments in that question](https://gist.github.com/clouddueling/70cee9b67077bd93b228)