# Sailsjs one-to-many empty results

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I am new to sailsjs. Trying to change my application backend to sailsjs. Have an existing database that I need to use. Getting this empty error trying to use one-to-many association:

```
{
  "Result": [
    {
      "newCars": [],
      "name": 'Someone',
      "id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

These are structures of the two sample tables that I have:

```
table user
id  |   name
1   |   Someone  


table new_car
name    |   user_id
Audi    |   1
BMW     |   1
```

Models:
(I am not sure about namings of - association, collection and via)

```
//UserController.js
module.exports = {
  tableName: 'user',
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    newCars: {              //i can name this anything?
      collection: 'newCar',     //should this be new_car (table name)?
      via: 'user'           //this is one-side table name?
    }
  },
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false
};


//NewCarController.js
module.exports = {
    tableName: 'new_car',
    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        users: {
            model: 'User'
        }           
    },
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false
};
```

Controller:

```
Role.find(1).populate('newCars').exec(function (err, result){
    res.json({Result: result});
});
```

**I have added some questions I have in comments as well.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manged to fix it. It might be useful for some newbie like me out there. Just needed to identify the primary and foreign key.

```
//at the one side
id: {
    type: 'integer',
    primaryKey: true
}


//at the many side      
user: {
    columnName: 'user_id',
    model: 'user'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `collection` name to `newcar`. In `Sails`, whenever models are referenced in `via`, `collection`, `model` you need to use the lowercased name. Read more [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/concepts/ORM/Associations/Associations.md).

**Note**

You will need to allow `Sails` to create its own association tables. For instance, you need to create Models `User` and `Car` and let `Sails` do your mapping for you. It is done by internally by creating a `User_Car` (not necessarily the same name) table that maps `user_id` to `car_id`. This can be done simply by creating two `apis` using [`sails-generate-api`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-generate-api)

`$ sails generate api User`

`$ sails generate api Car`

Now your models look like:

```
//User.js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: 'string',

    cars: {
      collection: 'car',
      via: 'user'
    }
  }
};

// Car.js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: 'string',

    user: {
      model: 'user'
    }
  }
};
```

Now you can create a `User` by sending an `HTTP POST` to `/user` and Car to `/car`

To create an association `User=>Car` send an `HTTP POST` to `/user/:id/car/:id`

Now when you get the details of the `User` via `GET /user/:id`, all the `Cars` owned by the `user[:id]` will be populated.

Comment: thanks but still no luck after making the changes u suggested. looking at my table structures and your comment, should 'via' be  'user' or 'user_id'. note, tried changing it to user_id as well, but still empty result :(

Comment: is the `user_id` field created by `Sails` adapter?

Comment: no, my database existed as is before trying out sailsjs. user (id, name) and new_car(name, user_id)

Comment: I've edited my answer, your table structure should be changed

Comment: this was just an example to simplify the issue i am facing. my actual database is legacy and big, can't be changing its structure as other APIs are accessing it too. do you mean there is a way to just update the existing tables structure without changing much or affecting data? any idea?

Comment: Ohh, then you should be looking for something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795389/one-to-many-associations-using-existing-join-table.